# Is there any way to generate video from ppt with animation using aspose library in Java

Tags: java, aspose-slides

I have one requirement to generate the video from pptx file with animations. I am able to generate the video but animation are not getting applied in the video.

Comment: I couldn't find anything except interop in .Net framework. Is there any way without PowerPoint or windows dependencies

Answer (score 0):

At present the requested support is not available in Aspose.Slides API for exporting animations and transitions sequences to exported output. The tentative ETA for this feature to get available in API is Q2 of 2021. We will notify about the supported feature via blogs and social media news as soon as it will be available in the API.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.